Remove horizontal line between facet_wrap labels
I am using ggplot to make a three-panel figure. I want to facet_wrap by state and include the city name in the label however, when I do this a horizontal line appears between the state and city names. How can I remove the horizontal line?
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(333)

# Example dataset
df <- data.frame(
  state = c("North Carolina","North Carolina","North Carolina",
            "North Carolina","North Carolina","North Carolina",
            "Virginia","Virginia","Virginia"),
  city = c("Boone","Boone","Boone",
           "Elizabeth City","Elizabeth City","Elizabeth City",
           "Norfolk","Norfolk","Norfolk"),
  year = rep(seq(2000,2004,2),3),
  value = round(rnorm(9,100,50))
)

# Example plot (how can I remove the horizontal line between the state and city labels?)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~state+city)


Created on 2024-04-19 with reprex v2.1.0

I'm guessing you specifically want to use theme_bw(), yes? If you remove that, then no line between facets.

You can experiment with the themes. Eg. theme_light() will work.

If you prefer to keep the theme_bw(), one option is to create a new variable that concatenates the state and the city, separated by newline (\n) characters:
df <- df %>%
  mutate(state_city = paste(state, city, sep = "\n\n"))

Then you can use the new variable to display your chart:
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~state_city)

Therefore full code is going to be:
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(333)

# Example dataset
df <- data.frame(
  state = c("North Carolina","North Carolina","North Carolina",
            "North Carolina","North Carolina","North Carolina",
            "Virginia","Virginia","Virginia"),
  city = c("Boone","Boone","Boone",
           "Elizabeth City","Elizabeth City","Elizabeth City",
           "Norfolk","Norfolk","Norfolk"),
  year = rep(seq(2000,2004,2),3),
  value = round(rnorm(9,100,50))
)

#New variable
df <- df %>%
  mutate(state_city = paste(state, city, sep = "\n\n"))

# Example plot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~state_city)



There's a few ways to achieve this. Change the theme, eg. to theme_light (A), or tinker with the strip background and text colours (B). Neither of these methods modify the data.
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_light() +
  facet_wrap(~state+city)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~state+city) +
  theme(strip.background=element_rect(color="grey90", fill="grey90"),
        strip.text=element_text(colour="black"))


